# How to do a sensitivity analysis for a Bayesian Model? Prior or Posterior?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, sensitivity-specificity

I'm developing a mathematical (SIR-style) model for cholera transmission in the Bengal Delta which is fit to data using MCMC.
The purpose of the model is more explanatory rather than predictive, and I would like to find out which parameters are most influential to the output (and especially how particular combinations of parameters may be important). To do this I think I need to do a global sensitivity analysis and get some second order effects (I am using the R Package 'sensobol' for this).

My question is should I allow the parameters to vary according to the prior distribution or the posterior distribution? In the examples from the sensobol vignettes, they appear to be using the prior, but would it not make more sense to use the posterior? A particular problem I have when using the prior for this analysis is that, for most sampled parameter values, the output is just a time series of NAN - what should I do with that? Ignore them, and just take the non-NAN values?

Comment: It seems that you are confusing model parameters with data features, otherwise it is hard to understand what it is you are actually trying to do. In any case the fact that you are getting NaN values as output (of what?) just indicates that you are probably implementing something wrong, but it is impossible to know exactly what without more details.